# How to convert String password to hash

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, import, password

I am trying to import customers using `.csv` file. I did it using data flow profiles in magento. I have list of customers and passwords but I have passwords in string format. How to convert string password into `password_hash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert all the password to hash password. then  on the sheet use ***password_hash*** instead of ***password*** for set password.

Use magento core helper class for generate `hash_password:`

> ```
> Mage::helper('core')
> ->getHash('YOUR_PASSWORD', Mage_Admin_Model_User::HASH_SALT_LENGTH);
> ```

Comment: Where is the file with this `getHash` function located?

Comment: https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/170c1a51387428fb56f3ada2504d52a2b130360a/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php#L96-L105

Answer (score 1):

I needed to solve a similar problem to the OP, however, I needed to do it in a stand-alone script outside of Magento, so I extracted the important parts of the app into a single class for easy use.

Use it like:

```
$newPw = 'thisisatest'
$newPwHash = (new Magento_Admin_Password_Hasher())->generateHash($newPw);
echo $newPwHash;
```

Output: `fa3e2266de47f6284fed4664896435a0:kVqArQN8pRtvoBROR99xAOpLbUmnwzJo`

PHP class:

```
<?php 
class Magento_Admin_Password_Hasher {
    // From app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
    const CHARS_LOWERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    const CHARS_UPPERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    const CHARS_DIGITS = '0123456789';

    // From app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
    const HASH_SALT_LENGTH = 32;

    // Our own function to tie it all together with sane defaults.
    function generateHash($password)
    {
        return $this->getHash($password, self::HASH_SALT_LENGTH);
    }

    // From app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
    public function getRandomString($len, $chars = null)
    {
        if (is_null($chars)) {
            $chars = self::CHARS_LOWERS . self::CHARS_UPPERS . self::CHARS_DIGITS;
        }
        for ($i = 0, $str = '', $lc = strlen($chars)-1; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $str .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $lc)];
        }
        return $str;
    }

    // From app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
    public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
    {
        if (is_integer($salt)) {
            $salt = $this->/*_helper->*/getRandomString($salt);
        }
        return $salt === false ? $this->hash($password) : $this->hash($salt . $password) . ':' . $salt;
    }

    // From app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
    public function hash($data)
    {
        return md5($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.x uses below encryption scheme for hashing passwords

`md5(salt.password):salt`

**Example:**

Let say your salt value is = `Stack88135`

And your chosen password is = `P@SS!2020`

then putting it all together

```
md5(Stack88135.P@SS!2020):Stack88135
```

so the resultant hashed password would be

```
9d15c6206d90f9a7fdbaf2c179c40bc4:Stack88135
```

Answer (score -3):

```
string password_hash ( string $password , integer $algo [, array $options ] )
```

Referrence 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Use it like this
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";

Comment: This does not match magento hash function.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831142/has-the-hash-password-function-changed-in-magento-if-so-to-what